Is it possible to use auth.js with express.js as a standalone REST API server?
Use case when client-frontend is developed separately using pure react, to consume backend Auth.js + Express.js API.
Thing that confuses me the most is that Auth.js (next-auth.js) 'authorize' callback always has to return User object.
How would one then actually return different status codes and/or json on successful/unsuccesful authentication?
Code example always returns 302 on Auth.js POST API call to predefined Auth.js route: /api/auth/callback/credentials
app.set('trust proxy', true);
app.use(
  '/api/auth',
  ExpressAuth({
    providers: [
      Credentials({
        credentials: {
          email: {},
          password: {},
        },
        authorize: async (credentials) => {
          // logic to verify if the user exists
          const user = await getUserByEmail(credentials.email);

          if (!user) {
            throw new InvalidCredentials();
          }

          // Compare the hashed password
          const isPasswordValid = await comparePassword(
            credentials.password,
            user.hashedPassword,
          );

          if (!isPasswordValid) {
            throw new InvalidCredentials();
          }

          //return user object with their profile data
          return user;
        },
      }),
    ],


Short answer: dont (yet), maybe there are plans in future, but as I see it now, it should be used alongside express server side rendering.
